# (Window) MPJExpress - runtime.MPJRuntimeException: Cannot connect to the daemon at machine <x> and port <10000>

Tags: amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mpj-express

I'm new to EC2. I have successfully created a window server 2012 hpc cluster using Amazon Web Service and hope to run parallel programming.

I have successfully run MPJ Express in the Multi-core configuration. However, I am facing some problem with cluster Configuration with niodev. My head node not able to connect to the compute node.

I have followed the instruction given at http://mpj-express.org/docs/guides/windowsguide.pdf. I have setup all the enviroment variable.

[Screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA4Hs.jpg)

The IP address i put in machines file is Private IP of compute node.

My machines file is put inside directory c:\mpj-user.

My compute node have started mpj daemon with same MPJExpress Configuration.

I am able to ping from head node to compute node.

I found out most of the solution on Internet is using ubuntu, I can't really find a solution for windows.

Any help or solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to start daemons on each compute node separately with same mpjepxress configurations and then try to run hello world program.
2. If that does not work, use -src switch if there is no Network File sharing enabled. You can find information about this switch in windows guide.

Let me know if you still get the problem.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. I have start the daemon on each compute node seperately with same mpjexpress configurations. I have also enable the file sharing for domain. It's still doesn't work.